# Laravel Getting Average of data of different users using eloquent

Tags: laravel

I have done a function where I calculate the average value of score given to different users differently . Mean Different user's scores average is calculated differently .

I want this function to be done with the help of eloquent so that I can use the ralationships of this model

```php
    $data = \DB::table('cleaning_scores')
                ->select(\DB::raw('avg(score) as avg, user_id'))
                ->groupBy('user_id')->orderBy('avg','DESC')
                ->get();
```

This is my CleaningScore.php Model

```php
    <?php

      namespace App;

     use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

     class CleaningScore extends Model
     {
         protected $fillable = ['user_id','score','giver_id'];

         public function users()
         {
            return $this->belongsTo(User::class , 'user_id');
         }
         public function givers()
         {
            return $this->belongsTo(User::class , 'giver_id');
         }
     }
```

THis is User Model

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable,HasRoles;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password','room_id'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function rooms()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Room::class , 'room_id');
    }

    public function scores()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Score::class);
    }

    public function cleaning_scores()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(CleaningScore::class);
    }

    public function own_rooms()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Room::class);
    }

    public function own_scores()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(CleaningScore::class);
    }

    public function rankings()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Ranking::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Could you please add Models and relationships to your answer?

Comment: Yes Just Added Can you check it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want? A eloquent query with model?

```
$data = CleaningScore::select('user_id', \DB::raw('avg(score) as avg'))
            ->groupBy('user_id')->orderBy('avg','DESC')
            ->get();
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

for single user Average then you can use elequent relationship like that :

```
  User::find(2)->cleaning_scores()->avg('score')
```

for multiple user Average  :

```
CleaningScore::select(\DB::raw('user_id,AVG(score) as scoreavg'))
            ->groupBy('user_id')
            ->orderBy('scoreavg','DESC')
            ->get();
```